# Error return code of bash script is not the value I send

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm testing bash scripts error codes with a simple nginx config check:

**verifier**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Error codes
ERROR_INVALID_NGINX_CONFIG=2

function validate() {
  if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
  else
    echo Invalid config
    exit $2
  fi
}

sudo nginx -t
validate $? $ERROR_INVALID_NGINX_CONFIG
```

Then I have the caller script that calls the script to check if there was an error:

**caller**

```
#!/bin/bash

./verifier
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo ok!
else
  echo Error code: $?
fi
```

Then when I execute `./caller` and there's an nginx config error, it always prints error code 1 instead of 2:

```
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Invalid config
Error code: 1
```

I must be missing something simple, anyone can see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` is always the exit code of the last command. In your example this is probably the check in `if`.

You need to set a variable to the exit code and use that:

```
#!/bin/bash

./verifier
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
  echo ok!
else
  echo Error code: $RESULT
fi
```

Comment: You could also upvote the question if you take the effort of answering it :)